# Bing Ads API: The account ID is invalid

Tags: php, bing-api

We are facing a problem with Bing Ads API version 9 and 10.

We are using the `ConstructWithAccountAndCustomerId()` method of the `ClientProxy class`, providing a valid *DeveloperToken*, *AccountId*, and *AuthenticationToken* (OAuth), like so:

```
$proxy = ClientProxy::ConstructWithAccountAndCustomerId($wsdl, null, null, $DeveloperToken, $AccountId, null, $AuthenticationToken);
```

Our goal is to retrieve and list all campaigns for an account. However, when running:

```
print_r($proxy->GetService()->GetCampaignsByAccountId($AccountId));
```

...we are faced with this error:

```
[Code] => 1102 
[Details] => AccountId is invalid 
[ErrorCode] => CampaignServiceInvalidAccountId 
[Message] => The account ID is invalid.
```

Now we've double and triple checked that the AccountID is right (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bing-ads-getting-started.aspx#accountcustomerid).

We've also tried this with both Bing Ads API v9, and Bing Ads API v10 - as well as the [Bing Ads SDK Api by CPCStrategy](https://github.com/CPCStrategy/bing-ads-sdk-php) - no dice anywhere.

Any ideas on what we are missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem and solution was ridiculously straightforward: the *GetCampaignsByAccountId* service operation requires a special *request object*, the *Account ID* in itself is not enough:

```
$request = new GetCampaignsByAccountIdRequest(); 
$request->AccountId = $AccountId; 
$request->CampaignType = CampaignType::SearchAndContent;
```

With this object defined and then feed to the *GetCampaignsByAccountId* service operation, all campaigns of the account are successfully returned:

```
print_r($proxy->GetService()->GetCampaignsByAccountId($request));
```